# Running symfony with directadmin

Tags: apache, symfony, directadmin

I have been trying to get symfony to run, next to a directadmin install. However, after trying several solutions, I have no clue how I can fix the httpd.conf file to get it to work. I'm only getting "Apache is functioning normally" right now.

Would anyone have an idea as to what my httpd.conf should look like?

I created the httpd.conf file by setting up a custom template for directadmin, basically working from what directadmin normally supplies by itself.

This is what the part for this subdomain looks like (IP/Domain have been hidden):

```
    <VirtualHost IP:443 >
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/admin/domains/DOMAIN.cert
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/admin/domains/DOMAIN.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/admin/domains/DOMAIN.cacert  
        ServerName www.sym.DOMAIN
        ServerAlias www.sym.DOMAIN sym.DOMAIN 
        ServerAdmin webmaster@DOMAIN
            DocumentRoot /home/admin/domains/DOMAIN/private_html/sym/web
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/admin/domains/DOMAIN/public_html/sym/cgi-bin/
        UseCanonicalName OFF
        <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
            SuexecUserGroup admin admin
        </IfModule>
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/DOMAIN.sym.bytes bytes
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/DOMAIN.sym.log combined
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domains/DOMAIN.sym.error.log
        <FilesMatch "\.(inc|php|phtml|phps|php70)$">
            AddHandler "proxy:unix:/usr/local/php70/sockets/admin.sock|fcgi://localhost" .php70
        </FilesMatch>
            <Directory /home/admin/domains/DOMAIN/private_html/sym/web>
                AllowOverride None
                Order Allow,Deny
                Allow from All
                <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                    Options -MultiViews
                    RewriteEngine On
                    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
                </IfModule>
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

The differences in here compared to a default subdomain generated by directadmin, are the addition of /web behind the documentroot, and the complete "directory" settings.